NullInjector error in standalone component
I got error that I have no provider for serviceX
To make it more readable I will describe schema
I got standalone componentX which imports MyModule.
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'app-component-x',
  templateUrl: './component-x.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component-x.component.css'],
  imports: [MyModule]
})
export class ComponentX {
  constructor(private serviceX: ServiceX) {}
}

MyModule has import and export ModuleX and in providers array got ServiceX.
@NgModule({
  imports: [ModuleX],
  exports: [ModuleX],
  providers: [ServiceX]
})
export class MyModule {}

ModuleA imports OtherModule and has also provider ServiceX
@NgModule({
  imports: [OtherModule],
  providers: [ServiceX]
})
export class ModuleA {}


with that I got No provider for ServiceX...
Additionally I check my .mjs file in dist folder. There I can see that ServiceX is declared in that file.
What is the issue with it ?

Where is located the component ComponentX? on ModuleA?

You should import the commonModule in your standalone component
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'app-component-x',
  templateUrl: './component-x.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component-x.component.css'],
  imports: [CommonModule,MyModule]
})


Doesnt work , :/

Try add
{
  provideIn: 'root',
}

to @Injectable decorator in ServiceX, if it possible.

Its external library so its not possible

What's your library? Is it implementing forRoot pattern?
https://v17.angular.io/guide/singleton-services#the-forroot-pattern
If your app is build on standalone components, in main.ts, you're supposed to import an appConfig. Add importProvidersFrom(MyModule.forRoot()), to the providers of this appConfig. This will extract providers from the module and provide them as singletons in your app.
  export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
     providers: [
        // default stuff
        provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }),
        provideRouter(routes), 
        provideAnimationsAsync(),

        // add this line
        importProvidersFrom(MyModule.forRoot()),
     ]
  };

https://angular.dev/api/core/importProvidersFrom
